# Cannot get Text Data from 000webhost in my Android Studio project with Java code

Tags: java, c#, android-studio, unity-game-engine, web-hosting

I am new in Android Studio development, however, I am experienced in Unity3D C# development. I have a PHP Script that returns some text data and it is hosted on 000webhost. I can retrieve that data using Unity3D C# script using `UnityWebRequest` class and its `downloadHandler.text`.

Now I am trying that in Android Studio Java. The problem is that I cannot get the data from the PHP Script. I tried the same code with a different URL, and it works. I tried changing the URL to "www.bing.com" and it displays the data of that Bing Webpage. It only cannot fetch data from 000webhost. Please tell me what is the problem with Android Studio (Java) and 000webhost.

Here is my code:

```
@Override protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
{
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://000webhost_URL"); // www.bing.com works
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line = "";
        while (line != null) {
            line = br.readLine();
            data = data + line;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
{
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    Log.d(tag, "Fetched data: " + data);
}

/*
I get empty Data when it is fetched from 000webhost
Fetched data: 

When I try from bing.com I get the response stream:
Fetched Data: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta content="text/html; /....
*/
```

Comment: Does a stacktrace appear ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout, I have edited the question. I get empty data when fetching from 000webhost. but when I fetch from bing.com, I get the response data stream. I check the output in Logcat.

Comment: I think your URL simply contains nothing then. Could you double check you have something when you fetch the URL with your browser / postman, etc ?

Comment: Also, is the device connected to the internet, and has given the app sufficient permissions ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout, I told you I get data when I change the url. Only when I use 000webhost URL, I get empty data. I am connected to internet and given internet permission to my app. When I try same 000webhost URL from my Unty3D C# game , I get the data. Also when I try 000webhost URL through browser, I get the text diplayed in browser.

Comment: @ArthurAttout, I have mentioned dummy url here. I hesitate to mention original 000webhost url for security concern. Hope you understand. Is there anything such as 000webhost does not respond to Android Studio Java API calls.